# android sdk manager not showing all packages

Tags: android, sdk

the SDK manager only shows android 4.2 package which is installed and 2 items in extras and API 19 and tools. i tried enabling and disabling forces HTTPSand clearing the caching. nothing works

Comment: btw am running revision 21.1.1

Comment: Have you enabled "Updates/New" in the Android SDK Manager windows?

Comment: yes and i also tried disabling  windows firewall

Comment: sorry for the spelling mistake. am running 21.0.1